# font awsome icons didn't changing

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div>
  <i id="icons" class="far fa-heart"></i>
</div>
```

I don't know why this code doesn't changes the icons as script is linked and the console didn't show any error as well

```
let icons = document.getElementById("icons");
icons.addEventListener("click", () => {
  icons.classList.remove = "far fa-heart";
  icons.classList.add = "fas fa-heart";
  console.log(icons);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
icons.classList.remove=("far fa-heart");
icons.classList.add=("fas fa-heart");
```

replace above lines of code with this :

```
icons.classList.remove("far fa-heart");
icons.classList.add("fas fa-heart");
```

Comment: still not works